# XmlService in Google Apps Script not getting attributes

Tags: google-apps-script, xml-parsing

I am using the XmlService in GAS to parse a document.  All is going well until I try to get the attributes of an element.  The XML looks like this:

```
<Cell ss:MergeAcross="5" ss:StyleID="S102">
  <Data ss:Type="String">2-28-17 test</Data>
</Cell>
```

I have the Cell element, but this code:

```
console.log(Have Cell attributes ' + JSON.stringify(element.getAttributes()));
```

Returns the right number of attributes, but empty:

```
Have Cell attributes [{},{}]
```

The same thing happens when I try to get attributes by name. Any idea why this is happening?  Am I missing something?  Is it because of the ss namespace?

Thanks for any tips or pointers.

Comment: I removed the ss namespace and it still failed, so that is not it.

Comment: Did you check the [Class Element](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/element#getAttributes()) from the docs?

Comment: @noogui, Yes, I have read the doc.  Or are you saying I am missing something?